# PhpStorm: Disable PHPDoc auto generation

Tags: phpstorm

I have a function like this:

```
public function someString() {
  return 'someString';
}
```

In PhpStorm, when I type /** above the method and press Enter, I get this:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
```

Is there any way to disable this?  I've already turned off Settings->Editor->Smart Keys->Insert documentation comment stub.

**Update** I can get most of the way there by editing the templates in *Settings->Editor->File and Code Templates->Includes Tab*.  However, it still autocompletes the PHPDoc block.  Is there any way to disable autocomplete completely?

Comment: Well ... the original suggestion (in a ticket for v1 or so) was to type space after `*` before pressing Enter .. but since then the `/**[space]` gets auto-transformed into inline PHPDoc version `/** [caret] */` .. and this "trick" does not work anymore. In theory disabling suggested `Insert documentation comment stub` option should do the job ... but since it does not work .. I may only suggest to file a ticket to the Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . P.S. Any particular reason as to why you want to disable such behaviour?

Comment: @LazyOne I use a multiple editors day-to-day, so I prefer to rely on muscle memory rather than keep track of which auto-complete features are supported by whatever editor I'm in.  I turn off automatic close-braces, etc. for the same reason.  I like the syntax highlighting and other passive features of PhpStorm, but I always prefer my editors to get out of the way and just let me type.

Comment: you can create live template. For example shortcut can be ** and expand this template to the phpdoc. You type ** hit tab and that`s it.

Comment: Is it not this? Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes > PHP Function Doc Comment.

Comment: @goulashsoup no.

Comment: In 2024, PHPDoc has lost its relevance starting from PHP 8, but IDEs still generate this documentation. I only use PHPDoc for a brief description of the method and do not include arguments, as it essentially duplicates the method signature. I waste time deleting this automatically generated code.